# reactjs : Re-rendering the page after removing a cart item not happening

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to render the page again after an item in the cart is removed so that the cart page does not display the item.

I am trying to use useEffect and useState for that as below, the cartItem state is getting set but the page wont re-render.

```
const CartItem = ({item}) =>
{   

  const {line_items} = useCartState() // to get cart details 

  const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([{}])

  const cartOnLoad = async() =>{
  setCartItems(line_items)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   cartOnLoad()
   console.log('from useEffect',cartItems)
  },[cartItems])
  
    const removeItem = async() => {

        await commerce.cart.remove(item.id)
        console.log(line_items)
        await cartOnLoad()
        console.log('from remove items', cartItems)
    }


    if(!item.line_total) return <p>'Loading...'</p> // We need to find an alternative to this

    else
      {

    return (

<div className="border-t border-b border-gray-200 divide-y divide-gray-200">
  <div className="flex py-6 sm:py-10">
    <div className="flex-shrink-0">
              <img
                src={item.image.url}
                alt={item.name}
                className="w-24 h-32 rounded-md object-center object-cover sm:w-48 sm:h-64"
               />
             </div>    

            <div className="ml-4 flex-1 flex flex-col justify-between sm:ml-6">
              <div className="relative pr-9 sm:grid sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-x-6 sm:pr-0">
                <div>
                  <div className="flex justify-between">
                    <h3 className="text-sm">
                      <a href="#" className="font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800">
                        {item.name}
                      </a>
                    </h3>
                  </div>

                  <p className="mt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{item.price.formatted_with_symbol}</p>
                </div>


                  <div className="absolute top-0 right-0">
                    <button type="button" className="-m-2 p-2 inline-flex text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" 
                    onClick={removeItem}>
                      <span className="sr-only">Remove</span>
                      <XIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                
  
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    )
}
}

export default CartItem
```

useCartState() is a context here

They page just wont re-render
Any ideas here? thanks!

below is the context

```
import {createContext, useEffect, useContext, useReducer} from 'react'
import {commerce} from '../../lib/commerce'
//need to correct this file to be a tsx file in the future

//Provides a context for Cart to be used in every page

const CartStateContext = createContext()
const CartDispatchContext = createContext()

const SET_CART = "SET_CART"

const initialState = {
    total_items: 0,
    total_unique_items: 0,
    subtotal:[],
    line_items: [{}]
}


const reducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_CART:
            return { ...state, ...action.payload }
        default: 
            throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}` )
    }

}

export const CartProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    const setCart = (payload) => dispatch({type: SET_CART, payload})

    useEffect(() => {
        getCart()
    },[]) 

    const getCart = async() => {
        try {
            const cart = await commerce.cart.retrieve()
            
            setCart(cart)

            } catch (error){

         console.log("error")
        }
    }

return (
    <CartDispatchContext.Provider value = {{setCart}}>
      <CartStateContext.Provider value = {state}>
          {children}
      </CartStateContext.Provider>
     </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
)
}

export const useCartState = () => useContext (CartStateContext)
export const useCartDispatch = () => useContext (CartDispatchContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

On React, avoid modifying the array, generate a new array to maintain immutability

```
const removeItem = async (itemId) => {
      await commerce.cart.remove(itemId)

      const updatedCart = [...cartItems];
      const itemIndex = updatedCart.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === itemId
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        updatedCart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        setCartItems(updatedCart);
      } else {
        throw new Error();
      }
  };
```